# Accessing @MappedSuperclass' properties in Criteria Query using metamodel classes

Tags: jpa, criteria-api, metamodel

I'm trying to access a property defined in `@MappedSuperclass` in a `Criteria Query` with JPA meta-model (Hibernate 4.2.8):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    private DateTime createdOn; 
}
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HISTORY")
public class History extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
}
```

How to access `createdOn`?

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<History> c = cb.createQuery(History.class);
Root<History> h = c.from(History.class);
h.orderBy(cb.asc(a.get(History_.createdOn)));
```

History_:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(History.class)
public abstract class History_ extends com.test.BaseEntity_ {
public static volatile SingularAttribute<History, Long> id;
}
```

Is there a way to access base class' properties?

Comment: @Andrei This must be the dumbest question of 2013.... Can you please answer the question, i'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a way. As I see in your code, you already access it: `History_.createdOn` is a property of the MappedSuperclass. If by "to access" you mean to select, than you simply do:

```
query.select(History_.createdOn)
```